# selenium with IE: click button to download the file, and then clicks other buttons, the process will be stuck

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iedriverserver

By using selenium with IE 11 and Python 3.6.3, need to download `Excel` and `PDF` files from Website with selenium：

1. click download button
2. send keys `S` to save file
3. click other button to download

When I execute the third step, my code was stuck without any exception.

Key Code:

```
def _click_excel(self):

    for i in range(self.retry_times):
        try:

            self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Excel Download'))).click()
            return ErrCode.add(ErrCode.SUCCESS)

        except Exception as err:
            logger.error("statement  error：{}".format(err))

    return ErrCode.add(ErrCode.CURRENT_MENU_HAS_CHANGED, "statement  error")

def _send_save_keys():
    # send  ALT + S 

    # statements

def _click_view(self, item, inner_height):
    for i in range(self.retry_times):
        try:

            xpath = '//a[@id="rq{}"]'
            self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath.format(item)))).click

            return ErrCode.add(ErrCode.SUCCESS)

        except Exception as err:
            logger.error("statement  error：{}".format(err))

    return ErrCode.add(ErrCode.CURRENT_MENU_HAS_CHANGED, "statement  error")
```